# Problem while connecting Spring boot with MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, gradle

I want to connect mongodb with spring project. But i faced the NullPointerException. How can I use save() in Interface MongoRepository? Should I make concrete class and override it?

about Interface MongoRepository: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html

I dont know much about Java, Spring, DI(Dependency Injection).

```
[Test.java]

@SpringBootTest
class PatientsServiceTest {

    private PatientsService patientsService = new PatientsService();

    @Test
    void save() {
        Patients patient = new Patients();
        
        ~~~ object patient initialize ~~~

        patientsService.save(patient);
    }
}
```

```
[PatientsService.java]

@Service
public class PatientsService {

    @Autowired
    public PatientsRepository patientsRepository; // <- Null exists

    public void save(Patients patients){
        

        ~~~ additional codes ~~

        
        patientsRepository.save(patients);
    }
}
```

```
[PatientsRepository.java]

@Repository
public interface PatientsRepository extends MongoRepository<Patients, String> {
    public Patients findBySSN(String SSN);
}
```

[error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUloN.png)

Comment: Is line 42 of the PatientsServiceTest class the one that calls `patientsService.save(patient);`?

Comment: What happens if you autowire your PatientsService in your test instead of creating an instance by yourself?

Comment: You have to autowire     private PatientsService patientsService = new PatientsService(); like this    @Autowired private PatientsService patientsService;

Comment: Can you also post your entity class? Does it have a primary key? Also, can you double-check your DB connection properties?

Comment: @VishalPawar It works ! thx